# How can i get the Page-ID in a Wordpress Shortcode in Visual Composer Header

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

i'm building my site using the visual composer header and footer functionality. I'm developing a shortcode which prints out my header html code. Then i'm embedding it in a new Header created using Visual Composer.

[image]

I updated the plugin (visual composer) today to version 13.12.2019 – ver 6.1.0 and now i'm not able to get the page-id in which the header is actually shown in the frontend. Previously i used this code to get the Page-Id on which the header is actually shown below (shortcode seems to run in header context).

```
$pageId = get_queried_object_id();
```

Even `global $wp_query;`does not contain the right ID.

Anyone here who can help me ;)?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this by myself. If anyone is in the same Situation, here is the solution to this. There is a function called `get_page_by_path()` in wordpress which searches for your page based on the `permalink`. I'm using this code in the Shortcode, which is included in the Visual Composer Header-Element and displayed in a subpage, to get the Page-ID from the site which includes the header and not the Header iteself (which is a posttype in wordpress too).

```
$pageId = get_page_by_path($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])->ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

get current page id or post id on the frontend

```
$page_id = get_the_ID();
OR
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

get term id on archive page on frontend

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $category->term_id;
```

Comment: No, i'm still getting the ID of the Visual Composer Header Element in whichs context the Shortcode is running.